# How can I select a range of indexes from an array?

Tags: php, arrays

In python I would do this:

```py
var = ["test","test1","test2","test3"];
test= var[1:3];
```

Then variable 'test' would be `["test1","test2","test3"]`

How can I do this in PHP?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That would be `array_slice($var, 1, 3)`. See also: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php.

Complete example:

```
$var = array("test","test1","test2","test3");
$test = array_slice($var, 1, 3);
```

Comment: Of note is that python's `[]` operator selects by index on the 2nd value in the question but in this answer php's `array_slice`'s second argument is by desired length of output, though this answer for sure works, that's just something people should be aware of.